# Prompt Resharper to Find References

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, resharper

I have a large C# ASP.Net solution which consists of a central Core ASP.Net website project and around 20 other projects which contain plugins to the system which are composed with MEF. (plugins are copied to the main project during build)

All of these 20 other projects have dependencies on a number of javascript / html projects - for example Bootstrap.

I am not keen to have 20 copies of bootstrap (and .js/.css things) in the solution so instead we simply have one in the Core project and simply have html includes which reference the location of the files in the Core project.

However Resharper doesn't know anything about this and we have nearly 1000 warnings about unfindable references in HTML. Is it possible to give a prompt to Resharper to tell it where to find Bootstrap ?

I know I could add resharper ignore comments to the individual files but wondered if there was an easier option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include all that files in each plugin project with linked files.
ReSahrper will see them and you will still have one copy of them in one physical folder.

Comment: how do I set this up? would it transfer between developers via GitHub?